# Materialize: Style of navbar search input broken when using typeahead.js (meteor)

Tags: css, meteor, typeahead.js, materialize

I am trying to integrate typeahead using sergeyt:meteor-typeahead in a project where I am using Materialize as the UI framework. 

Before typeahead integration, the search input field in the navbar is changing color to white on focus. Here's an example code:
[Materialize Navbar Search](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Hcwc2jXvxjeYQJkQc/Materialize%20Navbar%20search)

After integrating typeahead, the search is no longer switching to white color on focus. Also the materialize close icon added after the input field is not coming in the same line. 

How can this be fixed?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.


Thanks

[Removed original link to code due to restriction for new accounts]

EDIT: I added !important to all the styles related to input-field in Materialize css and things improved a bit. The color change to white on focus is working. But the icons are still sort of broken.
The icon on the front gets hidden and the close icon is still not on the same line. 

The current code is at: [Materialize Navbar Icons still broken](http://meteorpad.com/pad/F9vKN8FGZzPh82fis/Materialize%20Navbar%20search%20typeahead%20still%20broken)